# How to remotely control Banshee via SSH?

Tags: ssh, banshee, dbus

Banshee has the ability to control its main window from the command line using commands like

```
$ banshee --next
```

However when running these commands over ssh as the same user it simply tries to launch banshee.

Is there a way to push through to the other session when logged in with an ssh session.

I'm guessing this is more of an ssh/tty thing than a banshee thing but if it can be done I'd love to know.

Edit:

```
export $(strings /proc/*/environ| grep DBUS_SESSION | tail -1)
```

seems to work in my use case. Note there is a lot of permission denied output but you can ignore that.

via: http://machine-cycle.blogspot.com/2010/12/ssh-and-dbus-sessions.html

if anyone has a cleaner fix would love to see it.

Answer (score 8):

My guess is you're using DISPLAY to just dump the session to the X server, but what you need to do is pop up the right dbus channel.

This is a bit of a pain, but I have it working (just to show what's going on, this is not a good solution):

This is run locally:

```
tag@loki:~$ env | grep dbus
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbusxa7L6dRCEH,guid=f7056d1d174a3f5b7c680b9c0000006c
```

And when I ssh in:

```
tag@loki:~$ export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-xa7L6dRCEH,guid=f7056d1d174a3f5b7c680b9c0000006c
tag@loki:~$ banshee --next
```

and it works fine :)

Hopefully someone with some dbus know-how can hop in :)

Comment: thanks for putting me on the right track, just need a way to get the dbus adress from the ssh connection and I should be sweet.